# C: How to access different types of anonymous or unnamed nested structs

Tags: c, struct, anonymous-struct

I noticed that there are a few ways to define structs inside other structs in C:

```
struct s {
    int abc;

    struct {
        int a;
    };

    struct {
        int b;
    } intern;

    struct i {
        int c;
    };

    struct i2 {
        int d;
    } intern2;

    struct i3 {
        int e;
    };
    struct i3 intern3;
};
```

This struct compiles fine using gcc or g++, so I assume all parameters are accessible in some way. I tried it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct s mystruct;

    mystruct.abc = 0;
    mystruct.a = 1;
    mystruct.intern.b = 2;
    mystruct.c = 3; // <-- does not compile
    mystruct.intern2.d = 4;
    mystruct.intern3.e = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Apart from the access `mystruct.c`, everything compiles (compile error message is `‘struct s’ has no member named ‘c’`). Am I accessing the struct parameters in the correct way? Are there alternatives? How do I access the `c` parameter?

Comment: just successful compilation is not suffice. Please go through warnings also to check possible error.

Comment: gcc -Wall -> `warning: declaration does not declare anything`

Comment: I know these warnings occur, I just wanted to know how to access all struct members or why no compiler error occurs when defining the struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code,

```
struct i {
        int c;
    };
```

there is no member variable of type `struct i` neither it qualifies for *anonymous structure* <sup>Note</sup>. If you create a variable of that type, you'll be able to access the member variable `c`, similar to what you've done for `struct i3` with `intern3` variable.

Adding a bit regarding the error message you're seeing,

> `struct s` has no member named `c`

because, in case of an anonymous structure, the members are *considered* a direct member of the containing structure. In case of a `struct` definition with a *tag*, that structure is not an anonymous structure and the member of the structure needs a structure variable of that type to be accessed.

---

NOTE:

Regarding *anonymous structure*, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.2.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> An unnamed member whose type specifier is a **structure specifier with no tag is called an
>   anonymous structure**; an unnamed member whose type specifier is a union specifier with
>   no tag is called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or union
>   are considered to be members of the containing structure or union. This applies
>   recursively if the containing structure or union is also anonymous.

Answer (score 3):

From the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html):

> As permitted by ISO C11 and for compatibility with other compilers,
>   GCC allows you to define a structure or union that contains, as
>   fields, structures and unions without names. For example:

```
 struct {
   int a;
   union {
     int b;
     float c;
   };
   int d;
 } foo;
```

> In this example, you are able to access members of the unnamed union
>   with code like ‘foo.b’.

You were able to get at `mystruct.a` because the structure had no tag. You can't get at your `mystruct.c` because the containing struct for `c` has the tag `i`.

Change:

```
 struct i {
        int c;
    };
```

to

```
struct {
    int c;
}
```

and you should be able to get at `mystruct.c`.

Comment: It's naively supported in C11, check my answer.

Comment: He said gcc and wanted to know why it didn't compile. It won't help get you through a compile if C11 allows it but your compiler won't.

Comment: First of all, the compilation error is a coding error, not dependent on compiler/standard. Secondly, compiler supports (extensions) are important when the expression is not naively supported by a standard.

Comment: also, `My read is that you shouldn't have been able to get at your mystruct.a.`..is not clear, too.

Answer (score 0):

Member `c` is declared inside inside `strut i`. And you are not creating any variable for `struct i`.

So, you can't access member `c`.

When you mention `mystruct.c`, it expects `c` to be a member of structure `s`, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

*If you don't name your dog, you can't call it*

That is exactly what *unnamed* says - it has no name, so you cannot access it by name.

The only reason to have unnamed members in a structure is if you are mirroring a structure given externally, and you don't care about specific pieces of it, so you name only the pieces you want to access.